# I accidentally `git init`ed my home directory. Now my command line prompt won't load

Tags: macos, command-line

Is there some way to enable hidden files on OSX without using the command line? This is a real Catch 22 since I can't use my command line to undo the thing that's preventing it from loading in the first place.

Alternately I was thinking there must be some way to open an alternate shell that doesn't load the same path as my current profile has configured. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas come to mind (ranked by ease):

- Download [Forklift](http://www.binarynights.com/forklift/) (also in App store) and enable "Show Invisible Files" in View
- You could try download another terminal (I prefer [iterm](https://www.iterm2.com/))
- Use your favorite text editor to make a script that does something like `rm -r ~/.git`
- As above, but make a script that does `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` which enables hidden files in finder